# How to ADDDATE() in Access using 'DAY' vs 'd'

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to create a 'Due Date' column where it takes the date from the 'DATE_OF' column and adds the dynamic variable, "DAYS".

```
SELECT DATEADD('DAY',TABLE1.DAYS,TABLE1.DATE_OF) AS DUE_DATE
FROM TABLE1
```

This is the format of the date from 'DATE_OF'
**04/16/14 12:00 AM

06/24/14 12:00 AM

04/01/14 12:00 AM**

DAYS uses only integers (Values between **10** and **90**).

But I keep getting this for every result
**12/30/99 12:00 AM**

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I referenced [mssqltips.com](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2509/add-and-subtract-dates-using-dateadd-in-sql-server/) and found that the abbreviation for 'DAY' is 'd'. When I changed this, it worked. I do not know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've come to figure out, there are dissimilarities between many other RDMS' SQL/functions and Access SQL/functions.

Unfortunately, `'DAY'` is not a proper *interval* when using the `DateAdd` function in MS Access. It is `'d'`.

For further note: If you were going to hardcode in a date, the `#` on either side of the date are required. More details can be found [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateadd.php)

Answer (score 2):

Access does not accept not accept the value 'DAY' in the ADDDATE() function.

A complete list of accepted values can be found [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateadd.php)
*Here are the details of the accepted values.*

---

**Value**   **Explanation**
yyyy    Year
q   Quarter
m   Month
y   Day of the year
d   Day
w   Weekday
ww  Week
h   Hour
n   Minute
s   Second